# on Windows npm install or npm i removes the node_modules npm folder

Tags: node.js, npm

So I've run the Windows installer for example https://nodejs.org/en/download and it installs Node and NPM that I can verify from command line by

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If I try and install `jest` then I run

```
npm install jest
```

I get a response like `added 290 packages, removed 228 packages, and audited 291 packages in 8s`

The 228 packages removed include the `npm` directory so I have to repair the whole node installation.

How can I stop npm removing itself?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure not to run this within node's own directory. You have no business there. Run it within your project (after initialising it with a package.json) or to install things globally use `-g`.

Comment: thing is i want to put everything node in 1 place.. and the -g flag for global install is defaulting to the C drive Users folder etc. Is there a way to override the g flag install dir ?

Comment: You could use a custom prefix using `npm config set prefix <whatever>` but I don't think that's the right way. User-installed packages should be separated from the core installation of node. Otherwise you will have big trouble when updating node or switching node version with a version manager!